# Added item language is not showing in Publish item

Tags: publishing, multilingual

When adding a new language to an item, it's not showing in my Publish item viewer.
Do I need to configure this somewhere else too?

[image]

Spanish and Dutch were added to this item, but when Publishing the item, I'm not getting the Publishing language.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you have directly created a language version of an item before adding the new language in Sitecore system settings.

**You need to follow the below steps to add a language to Sitecore system settings:**

1. In the Content Editor, go to */sitecore/System/Languages.*
2. Right-click and then click Insert, Language.
3. In the Add a New Language dialog box, in the Choose a predefined language code field, select the language and country code you want to use.
4. Complete the remaining fields as required and click Next to step through the remaining pages of the Wizard.
   [image]
5. When you are finished, click Close.

The new language is added to the content tree.

Now, if you go back to your item and try to publish it, you'll see new language will be there.

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Thank you.